# svnsync: Base checksum mismatch error

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svnsync

We are getting `Base checksum mismatch` error while syncing the mirror repository with the master repository. Then we load the new dump of master into mirror repository and again starting syncing the mirror.

Can anyone tell me why the bad checksum error occurred in sync command? What are all the possibilities for this error?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that someone commits a revision to the mirror server's repository directly, i.e. passing over the master server's repository. Then the error occurs because master and mirror (slave) repos are out of sync.

Make sure that the mirror server's repository has

- Read Only access for your users,
- Read / Write for the account which runs `svnsync`.

See [SVNBook | Write-through proxying](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.writethruproxy) or take a closer look at [Multisite Repository Replication (VDFS) feature](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/) of VisualSVN Server if you are looking for enterprise-grade solution that is not affected by such problems by design.

Comment: Yes, The mirror server is read only for all users except svnsync. there is no commit is happened in mirror by user.